# Overloaded boost::lexical_cast function

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I wish to write my own conversion function & **reuse boost::lexical_cast()**; thus I overloaded the boost::lexical_cast() function. After all, **boost::conversion::try_lexical_convert()** is added in the library for the same purpose.

My program works, **Overloaded lexical_cast()** is called in the first 2 cases since both the calls are made locally. In the third case, parent function boost::lexical_cast() is called since call to boost::lexical_cast() is routed through parse_date().

I want to handle all conversions through my lexical_cast() function. i.e. Whenever there is a call to boost::lexical_cast(), my overloaded function gets call.

Is there any way, I can write such a **global lexical_cast() function handler**?

Also, please suggest how can we make that global handler custom in such a way that it can only be called for selected few POD & boost data types, whenever they are specified.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <exception>

#include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

namespace boost
{
template<typename T>
T lexical_cast(const std::string &str)
{
    if(str.empty()) //handle preconditions here, some custom logic
        return T();

    T result;

    if (!conversion::try_lexical_convert(str, result))
        throw bad_lexical_cast();

    return result;
}
}

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::posix_time;
using namespace boost::gregorian;

int main(int ac, char* av[])
{
    try
    {
        //1.
        auto p1_ = lexical_cast<int>(std::string(""));
        std::cout << "p1 = " << p1_ << std::endl; //displays 0, which is correct. calls overloaded lexical_cast()

        //2.
        auto p2_ = lexical_cast<int>(std::string("1"));
        std::cout << "p2 = " << p2_ << std::endl; //displays 1, which is correct. calls overloaded lexical_cast()

        //3.
        std::locale locale_;
        boost::date_time::format_date_parser<boost::gregorian::date, char> parser_("", locale_);
        boost::date_time::special_values_parser<boost::gregorian::date, char> svp_;
        boost::gregorian::date date_ = parser_.parse_date("2014-Dec-17", "%Y-%b-%d", svp_);  //calls boost::lexical_cast(), but I want call to overloaded lexical_cast() instead.
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program "works" but flirts with Undefined Behaviour.

Redefining competing definitions of the exact same symbols in different translation units is technically a violation of the One-Definition-Rule.
You may get away with it here because it's merely about function instances and one will be visible/selected at a time. However,

- this doesn't make it more valid to "overload" library features.
- this has a capability to silently change the behaviour of other code included that internally (invisibly?) depends on `lexical_cast`. Especially a silent "fallback" to default constructed values for empty strings is a behaviorial change that library users might not cope with well. You basically violate the contract other clients had with boost lexical_cast

There's only structural pattern where users are invited to "overload" inside a library namespace and that is when extending the library at *designed-for* extension points (a.k.a. customization point in TMP). Often this entails

- specialization of a class (like `std::hash<>`, `boost::hash<>`, `boost::spirit::traits::is_container<>`, `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT()` etc.)
- adding an overload of a function that overloads on a parameter of User-Defined Type (like `std::swap`, perhaps `std::iter_swap`, but also `boost::serialization::serialize`. **Importantly** in this case, usually the namespace intrusion is not preferred and actually not required, as the overload can be declared inside a namespace *associated with* the user-defined type (e.g. `std::swap(mypgrogram::typeA&, mypgrogram::typeA&)` or even `std::swap(boost::optional<mypgrogram::typeA>&, boost::optional<mypgrogram::typeA>&)` can perfectly well be defined in namespace `::mypgrogram`) and the correct overload can then be resolved by the compiler, optionally in 2-phase lookup, using Argument Dependent Lookup (ADL)

So, unless Boost Lexicalcast documents such a ***customization point*** for you to use, there is no way in which you can reliably make this work for other modules (except perhaps if you can somehow  guarantee your definition to be seen by all invocations). In that case it would appear quite a way simpler to just alter Boost Lexicalcast in place. After all this is exactly what you intend to do.

**UPDATE**
If you reorder the includes in your TU you can have the effect you want. Note the use of SFINAE to restrict to (in this case) *integral types*:

```
template<typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<boost::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type 
        lexical_cast(const std::string &str)
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a038dfb2c50ee51)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <exception>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
namespace boost
{
    template<typename T>
        typename std::enable_if<boost::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type 
            lexical_cast(const std::string &str)
        {
            std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
            if(str.empty()) //handle preconditions here, some custom logic
                return T();

            T result;

            if (!conversion::try_lexical_convert(str, result))
                throw bad_lexical_cast();

            return result;
        }
}


#include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::posix_time;
using namespace boost::gregorian;

int main()
{
    try
    {
        //1.
        auto p1_ = lexical_cast<int>(std::string(""));
        std::cout << "p1 = " << p1_ << std::endl; //displays 0, which is correct. calls overloaded lexical_cast()

        //2.
        auto p2_ = lexical_cast<int>(std::string("1"));
        std::cout << "p2 = " << p2_ << std::endl; //displays 1, which is correct. calls overloaded lexical_cast()

        //3.
        std::locale locale_;
        boost::date_time::format_date_parser<boost::gregorian::date, char> parser_("", locale_);
        boost::date_time::special_values_parser<boost::gregorian::date, char> svp_;
        boost::gregorian::date date_ = parser_.parse_date("2014-Dec-17", "%Y-%b-%d", svp_);  //calls boost::lexical_cast(), but I want call to overloaded lexical_cast() instead.

        std::cout << date_ << "\n";
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
T boost::lexical_cast(const string&) [with T = int; std::string = std::basic_string<char>]
p1 = 0
T boost::lexical_cast(const string&) [with T = int; std::string = std::basic_string<char>]
p2 = 1
T boost::lexical_cast(const string&) [with T = short int; std::string = std::basic_string<char>]
T boost::lexical_cast(const string&) [with T = short int; std::string = std::basic_string<char>]
2014-Dec-17
```

Comment: Updated to include a working sample **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a038dfb2c50ee51)** - now with added Sfinae (even though I obviously still recommend against it)

Comment: Great answer! I knew that you would answer this. sehe at his best.